# Computing distance matrix for a list

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, functional-style

Using functional programming in Mathematica, how can I compute a distance matrix for every element in a list of matrices... The distance would be computed between the item in the list and a "target matrix".
For simplicity, let's consider that the list is a list of simple 3x2 matrices of integer with a range [0,4].
The target matrix is a matrix of that type as well. 
The reason I want to do that is to filter the list to find the matrix closest to the target one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(* source matrices *) 
as = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {10, 2, 2}]
```

> {{{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{2, 4}, {3, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 
>      4}}, {{2, 4}, {2, 0}}, {{3, 3}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 0}}, {{4, 
>      1}, {0, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {0, 2}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 0}}}

```
(* Target matrix *)
b = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}

Plus @@ Abs@Flatten@(# - b) & /@ as
```

> {5, 8, 5, 7, 6, 5, 2, 7, 6, 4}

If you prefer to use `EuclideanDistance` as a metric you can apply the following:

```
EuclideanDistance[b, #] & /@ as //N
```

> {2.61803, 4.13065, 3.60555, 4.30278, 3.23607, 2.92081, 1.41421, 
>   3.54138, 3.23607, 2.28825}

Comment: One might prefer to use a matrix norm for distances, e.g. `N[Norm[# - b, "Frobenius"] & /@ as]`. `Pick[]` can then be used: `Pick[as, %, Min[%]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes that would be a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

If the purpose is as in the following,

> *The reason I want to do that is to filter the list to find the matrix closest to the target one,*

then an alternative would be to use `Nearest`:

```
SeedRandom[2013];
matlist = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {100, 3, 2}];
dist[m1_, m2_] := Norm[m1 - m2, "Frobenius"];
nf = Nearest[matlist, DistanceFunction -> dist];

nf[{{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}}]
(* {{{2, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 3}}} *)

Position[matlist, First@nf[{{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}}]]
(* {{9}} *)
```

Comment: Alternatively, one can do `nf = Nearest[matlist -> Automatic, DistanceFunction -> dist]`, so that the `NearestFunction[]` returns the index of the nearest matrix instead of the matrix itself. One can then use `Part[]` or `Extract[]` to get the actual matrix afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will investigate this path as well :)